# Decidability of a predicate.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have the following problem:

Let the following predicates be: $P1, P2, Q1, Q1 : R \to \{0,1\} $ .

It is given that $P1 \lor P2$ and $Q1 \lor Q2$ are semidecidable and $P2 = \lnot Q2$

What can it be said about $P1 \lor Q1$?

I have searched all over the internet and I simply cannot understand the concept of decidability of a predicate, let alone a logic operation with predicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See **Herbert Enderton**, *Computability Theory An Introduction to Recursion Theory* (2011) [pag.4] :

> The concept of decidability can [...] be described in terms of functions: For a subset
>   $S$ of $\mathbb{N}$ , we can say that $S$ is *decidable* iff its characteristic function

$C^S(x)$ = Yes if $x \in S$

$C^S(x)$ = No  if $x \lnot \in S$

> is effectively calculable. Here “Yes” and “No” are some fixed members of $\mathbb{N}$, such as $1$ and $0$.

So, a predicate $P$ is *decidable* when you have an effective way (an algorithm) to check, for each $x$ in the domain of $P$, if $x$ is in $P$ (i.e. if $P(x)$ is true).

The class of effectively calculable functions (and predicates) is closed under standard logical operators (like $\land$ , $\lnot$, $\lor$) ; so, the conjunction of two decidable predicates $P$ and $Q$ (i.e. $P \land Q$) is again decidable.

From algorithms checking for membership into sets $P$ and $Q$ you can find an algorithm checking for membership into the intersection of $P$ and $Q$ (i.e.$P \cap Q$).

Take as an example the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ and let $P$ the predicate "_ is even", so that $P(x)$ is true for $x \in \mathbb{N}$ iff "$x$ is even".

Let $Q$ the predicate "_ is multiple of $5$"; now $P \land Q$ is the predicate "_ is even and multiple of $5$".

By usual arithmetical methods, you can check, for each number $x \in \mathbb{N}$, if $(P \land Q)(x)$ is true (e.g.it is true for $10$, $20$ ..., i.e.by all numbers divisible by $2$ and $5$).

Comment: Thank you for your response. What I still dont understand is how a Predicate can be semidecidable. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Actually it was so easy... i figured myself a predicate "_ is a prime gap". You cannot find a effective way to check for each x in the domain if it is a prime gap! The Algorithm will only give you an answer if it is a prime gap, and it will run forever otherwise.

Comment: Exactly. Take as example Propositional Calculus : the property of a formula A of being a Theorem is decidable. By Completeness, a formula is a Theorem of PC iff it is a Tautology; so, check with the algorithm of truth-tables and (in a finite number of steps) you will find if Taut(A). Consider now First-Order Logic : again, by completenss, a formula B is a Theorem iff it is Logically Valid. But, by Church's Theorem, Validity is not decidable. The only way you have is to start from FOL's axioms and derive theorems.

Comment: This procedure is effective BUT, given a FOL formula B, you do not know, in general, if it is Valid or not; so you must produce theorems and wait ... The set of Theorems of FOL is semi-decidable.

Comment: I still do not understand how should I proceed in finding the decidability of P1 v Q1.

Comment: If P and Q are both decidable, the predicate PvQ is also decidable with the following procedure. In order to check if PvQ is true for x, you must : first, check if P(x) is true; if YES, it's Ok. If NO, check now if Q(x) is true; if YES, it's Ok (in order for the disjunction PvQ to be true, it's enough that one of the two disjuncts is true). If both P(x) and Q(x) are false, then so is PvQ.

Answer (score 0):

About *semi-decidability*, we have that (again form Enderton's book, pag.5) :

> It is very natural to extend these concepts to the situation where we have half of
>   decidability: Say that S is semidecidable if its “semicharacteristic function”

$c^S(x)$ = Yes if $x \in S$

$c^S(x)$ = undefined  if $x \lnot \in S$

> is an effectively calculable partial function. Thus, a set S of numbers is semidecidable
>   if there is an effective procedure for recognizing members of S. We can think of S as
>   the set that the procedure accepts. And the effective procedure, while it may not be a
>   decision procedure, is at least an acceptance procedure.
>   Any decidable set is also semidecidable. If we have an effective procedure that
>   calculates the characteristic function $C^S$, then we can convert it to an effective procedure that calculates the semicharacteristic function $c^S$. We simply replace each “output No” command by some endless loop.

The fundamental theorem regarding these two concepts is (pag.9) :

> **Kleene’s theorem**: A set (or a relation) is decidable if and only if both it and its
>   complement are semidecidable.